# Why is NEQ not expected by CMD on processing the second IF condition?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code in a batch file:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C:12345 /M "1M(1)1F(2)2M(3)2N(4)3rd(5)"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==5 goto n3
IF ERRORLEVEL NEQ 5 echo incorrect try again
:n3
```

There is always output the following error message on pressing any other key than <kbd>5</kbd>:

> NEQ was unexpected at this time.

What does this mean?

I have tried various different syntax, but can't find anything online about what that error means.

Comment: The syntax should be ```IF ERRORLEVEL 5``` meaning if the error level was 5 or more; ```IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 5```, meaning if the error level was 5; ```IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 5```, meaning if the error level was anything except for 5; ```IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 5```, meaning if the error level was less than 5. Now as your command can only return `1`, `2`. `3`, `4`, or `5`, you cannot input an incorrect value, only any one of the single keys listed after ```/C```, not ```C:```.

Comment: Please read the chapter about usage of command __CHOICE__ in my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errorlevel` is just a string, the same was as are `socks` and `banana` and `62`.

`62` has a secondary meaning - it's a string but it's also a number.

`errorlevel` also has a secondary meaning - it's a number that describes the result of executing a command.

Originally, we could use

```
if %zombies%==62 ...
```

which would mean `if the *contents* of the variable "zombies" was exactly "62" (then do something)`

OR we could use

```
if errorlevel n ...
```

which would mean if the current `errorlevel` (ie the code returned from the last command [athough some commands do not alter the `errorlevel` value]) was `n`  **OR greater than ** `n` then do something.

This functionality remains.

Later, the comparison operator `==` was supplemented by {EQU NEQ GTR LSS GEQ LEQ} to enhance flexibility. Also by the `else` clause to specify instructions whould the comparison not be evaluated to `true`.

`IF ERRORLEVEL NEQ 5` yields a syntax error because batch is expecting a number after `errorlevel` or `==` (old syntax); but it finds `NEQ` (new syntax in conflict with old).

`IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 5` would work as you apparently expect because `%errorlevel%` retrieves the **value** of the current `errorlevel`.

**BUT** there's a trap. `%errorlevel%` retrieves the value of the **user-defined** variable `errorlevel` and only goes on to the **system-defined** value if there is no **user-defined** variable `errorlevel`.

Hence, of `errorlevel` is `6`, then executing

```
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
SET "errorlevel=banana"
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
SET "errorlevel="
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

will report

```
6
banana
6
```

Hence, it's highly unusual to assign a value to `errorlevel` or to the other magic variables like `random` or `cd`.